# Crude operation on the codeigner sets the value in the text field inside the edit page but does not display on the view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I set the values created in the text field in the edit form when I perform the crude operation on the codeignor but it does not show up on the view page, I do not know if there is any problem with the code Can anyone help?

database

CREATE TABLE system_usertable ( admin_id int(11) NOT NULL, role_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL, staff_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL, first_name longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, second_name varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL

model

```
 public function getuser($admin_id){
       $this->db->where('admin_id',$admin_id);
         return $user= $this->db->get('system_usertable')->row_array();
     }
```

controller

public function editusers($admin_id){

```
    $this->load->model('Crud_model');
    $user= $this->Crud_model->getuser($admin_id);
    $data=array();
    $data['user'] =$user;
    return view('admin/edituser', $data);
}
```

edit form

```
 <?php echo form_open(base_url('admin/adduserdetails/'.$user['admin_id']) , array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
                 
                            <label class="d-flex align-items-left fs-5 fw-bold mb-2"
                                for="name"><?php echo get_phrase('first_name:*'); ?></label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name',$user['first_name']); ?> "class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
                                id="first_name" name="first_name" required>

                

                 
                            <label class="d-flex align-items-left fs-5 fw-bold mb-2"
                                for="second_name"><?php echo get_phrase('second_name:*'); ?></label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('second_name',$user['second_name']); ?> "  class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
                                id="second_name" name="second_name" required>

               

                       
                            <label class="d-flex align-items-left fs-5 fw-bold mb-2"
                                for="email"><?php echo get_phrase('email'); ?></label>
                            <input type="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email',$user['email']); ?> " class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" id="email"
                                name="email" required>

                
                            <button type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-sm btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php echo get_phrase('Edit User');?></button>
                    


                    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: change this line to: `return $this->db->get('system_usertable')->row_array();` - don't set a $users variable in that same line

Comment: @Kinglish - Even though it doesn't make sense to have the `$user` variable there, removing it won't change anything. The value will still be returned.

Comment: Are you sure the admin_id is valid and exist in your db?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes this is my db                                                                     
                                                                                                                              
 CREATE TABLE `system_usertable` (
  `admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `second_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: FYI, the label's `for="name"` does not connect to `id="first_name"`.  No`get_where()`?

Comment: I meant if you're sure that your code gets the correct value in the `$admin_id`-variable. In your `getuser()`-method, add `var_dump($admin_id); exit;` as the first lines, submit the form and see what that variable actually contains at that point. Then check your database to make sure you really have a row where the `admin_id` column has that same value.